# Copy and paste values into one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a VBA code where it could copy all the unique file owner emails into one cell and all the file locations into the cell next to it, being separated by a comma. Is that possible?  I created a code to grab the unique values and pasted into cell L1 and create a table, and this is what I have so far:

[This is an example of what Excel would look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JDeQ.jpg)

[This is an example what I want the VBA code to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yduTD.jpg)

```vb
Public Sub unique_emails()

    Columns("B:B").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("L1" _
        ), Unique:=True
        
    Range("L1").Select
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Range(Range("L1"), Range("L1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
    tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium16"
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Unique Delimited (Dictionary)

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub unique_emails()
        
    Const sFirst As String = "A1"
    Const dFirst As String = "L1"
    Const Delimiter As String = ", "
        
    ' Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
        
    ' Source Range
    Dim rg As Range
    With ws.Range(sFirst).Resize(, 2)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set rg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    
    ' Source Range to Array
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim n As Long
    
    If rCount > 1 Then
        ' Array to Dictionary
        Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        Dim Key As Variant
        For n = 2 To rCount
            Key = Data(n, 2)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                    If dict.Exists(Key) Then
                        dict(Key) = dict(Key) & Delimiter & Data(n, 1)
                    Else
                        dict(Key) = Data(n, 1)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next n
        ' Dictionary to Array
        n = 1
        For Each Key In dict.Keys
            n = n + 1
            Data(n, 1) = Key
            Data(n, 2) = dict(Key)
        Next Key
    Else
        n = 1
    End If
    
    ' Switch Headers
    Key = Data(1, 1): Data(1, 1) = Data(1, 2): Data(1, 2) = Key
     
    ' Array to Destination Range
    With ws.Range(dFirst).Resize(, 2)
        .Resize(n).Value = Data
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - n + 1).Offset(n).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```